# Sisense - How To Customize UI

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, sisense

I'm a total Sisense noob, but am being tasked with customizing the look and feel of the Sisense app. Out of the box, it looks similar to:

[image]

For starters, I need to customize the header and left nav (highlighted in the screenshot above). I've read some of the Sisense documentation and lots of forums and posts, but am having trouble getting a straight answer to how to customize the UI. **How do I modify/override the existing HTML, CSS, and JavaScript for various elements on the page?** (may be 3 separate questions)

(**note:** Answers can include "it's actually easier to embed dashboards and widgets into your existing application")

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an add-on to your Sisense license to customize the sisense web app.

https://documentation.sisense.com/7-1/administration/embedded-analytics/rebranding-sisense/white-label.htm#gsc.tab=0

Comment: This "white labeling" seems to be limited to only changing images and some miscellaneous items like the welcome section content. This doesn't seem to help with actually touching any CSS, JS, or HTML.

Comment: You can also get access to dashboards and widgets data using their api and display as you like in your own web app.